# Compiling python ASCII error via powershell

Tags: python, powershell

i am confused..

i just start learning python 
i created a file using command line and when i execute it ... it through error..

command i use are

```
PS E:\python\mystuff> echo /n > test.py
PS E:\python\mystuff> type test.py
PS E:\python\mystuff> start 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe' .\test.py
```

file

then i edit it and print some stuff .. and when i run it .. it through error
file test.py
    print ("hello world")
    print "this is pyrhon"

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xff' in file test.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

after a while i run python and print those thinks .. it work well ... then i create a file ex1.py without command.. it works ... 
why the file i created using command line is not working and how do i solve it...
i am very new to python and powershell .. i just start learning ... please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When checking the url in the error message (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/), it confirms my suspicion that Python doesn't handle a Unicode file well.

You can either apply the fixes mentioned on that page, or you can enforce an ASCII encoding on your file from within Powershell:

```
"" | Out-File ".\test.py" -Encoding ascii
```

This replaces the `echo /n` command.